# Joined objects remain separated in edit mode

Tags: mesh

I apologize if this has been covered, but I have been unable to locate a solution.

I joined two basic objects together before applying array and curve modifiers, but they are still detached in edit mode. Is there a way to combine all vertices into one complete object? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: detached]

Comment: Try selecting the whole mesh, then select `mesh > clean up > merge by distance`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried both "merge by distance" options and "delete loose", but still the same result.

Comment: This looks normal... why / which parts of the mesh do you want to be connected?

Comment: I joined the laces to the patch and I want to move them as one piece in edit mode. It is acting as if they are still sperate objects.

Comment: Hello :). Since you're using Proportional editing, make sure the *Connected Only* option is disabled.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was something simple.

Comment: When you use 'merge by distance' in the pop up window it lets you specify the distance. By default it's so low that it only merges vertices that perfectly overlap. Try setting it to something bigger like 0.01 and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

if the vertices are close enough , you can Select all the vertices and click x to delete and do by distance , or else if you want to do manual work you can CTRL M to merge pairs of corresponding mesh vertex